# Whats's the order of K-project manga?

Tags: k-project

I want to read the K Project manga, but there are a lot of series. So what's the order for these series?

Comment: I have not seen/read K-project. Since you are asking this question, perhaps it might be prudent to specify if you want it in chronological order or release order (if applicable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean publication order, the [K wikipedia article's manga section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28anime%29#Manga) doesn't list all the publication dates, but seems to list them in publication order.

By serialization publication start date (end date included if applicable/known):

- 2012 ? (no later than November) - 2013 ? (tankobon release 2013 April): K Stray Dog Story
- 2012 May - 2013 July: K -Memory of Red-
- 2013 October - 2014 July: K -Days of Blue-
- 2013 December - 2015 April: K - The First
- 2014 January: Gakuen K
- 2014 June: K: Lost small world
- 2014 December - 2015 July: K: Countdown
- 2015 April - August: K: Missing Kings
- 2015 May - November: K: Dog and Cat
- 2015 September: K: Dream of Green
- 2015 October: K: Return of Kings

Sources: [K Project wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28anime%29) and [Anime News Network Encyclopedia](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/).

Based on the various summaries and news articles, I've placed them in approximate chronological order (some of the stories overlap) using the anime series as a guideline.

Before K TV

- K: Lost small world
- K -Memory of Red-
- K -Days of Blue-
- K: Stray Dog Story

Adaptation of K TV

- K - The First

After K TV / Before Movie

- K: Dog and Cat

Adaptation of K Movie

- K: Missing Kings

After Movie / Before K TV2

- K: Countdown

Before and/or Overlaps with K TV2?

- K: Dream of Green

Adaptation of K TV2

- K: Return of Kings

Alternate story

- Gakuen K (comedy spin-off where all characters attend high school together)